# How to call useEffect by updating values in a Context provider with react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

What I'm trying is to test if a component, which depends on a context, calls `useEffect` and a function (mocked by `jest.fn()`) is called from there.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

`MyComponent.tsx`

```
export function MyComponent() {
    const ref = createRef();
    const { date } = useMyContext(); // "date" is a string (e.g. `2021-11-01`) 

    useEffect(() => {
        if (date && ref.current) 
            ref.current.scrollIntoView();
    }, [date, ref]);

    return (
        <div>
            {/* some other elements are here */}
            <AnotherComponent ref={ref} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

`MyComponent.test.tsx`

```
it('should scroll into AnotherComponent when date is updated', () => {
    const mockContextValue = { date: '2021-11-01' };
    window.HTMLElement.prototype.scrollIntoView = jest.fn();

    render(
        <MyContext.Provider value={mockContextValue}>
            <MyComponent />
        </MyContext.Provider>,
    );

    // update the date in MyContext.Provider 

    // then, useEffect should be called

    // then, expect scrollIntoView was called
});
```

I'm clueless as to how to

1. update the `date` value in `MyContext` after `MyComponent` is rendered by the render function of `@testing-library/react`
2. see if `useEffect` was called after the `date` was updated

I've been googling for hours and hours, but haven't found any solution.
Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [rerender](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#rerender) function of RTL, this function can be used to update props or context of the rendered component.

Besides, you don't need to assert the `useEffect` hook to be called. Because when Dependencies change, it will be called again, this is a behavior that has been fully tested, we don't need to test it.

We can also indirectly assert that `useEffect` is called by asserting whether `.scrollIntoView()` is called.

E.g.

`MyComponent.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRef, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AnotherComponent } from './AnotherComponent';

export const MyContext = React.createContext({ date: '' });

export function MyComponent() {
  const ref = createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
  const { date } = useContext(MyContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (date && ref.current) {
      console.log('date: ', date);
      ref.current.scrollIntoView();
    }
  }, [date, ref]);

  return (
    <div>
      <AnotherComponent ref={ref} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

`AnotherComponent.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export const AnotherComponent = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement>((props, ref) => {
  return <div ref={ref}>another</div>;
});
```

`MyComponent.test.tsx`:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { MyComponent, MyContext } from './MyComponent';

describe('70068118', () => {
  it('should scroll into AnotherComponent when date is updated', () => {
    const mScrollIntoView = jest.fn();
    window.HTMLElement.prototype.scrollIntoView = mScrollIntoView;

    const { rerender } = render(
      <MyContext.Provider value={{ date: '' }}>
        <MyComponent />
      </MyContext.Provider>
    );
    expect(mScrollIntoView).not.toBeCalled();

    rerender(
      <MyContext.Provider value={{ date: '2021-11-01' }}>
        <MyComponent />
      </MyContext.Provider>
    );
    expect(mScrollIntoView).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/70068118/MyComponent.test.tsx (9.695 s)
  70068118
    ✓ should scroll into AnotherComponent when date is updated (39 ms)

  console.log
    date:  2021-11-01

      at examples/70068118/MyComponent.tsx:13:15

----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                  | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files             |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 AnotherComponent.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 MyComponent.tsx      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.281 s
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you so much!